# Is multistep checkout supported?

Tags: commerce

I am wondering if Drupal 7 commerce support the multistep checkout via hook or contrib modules, the target was I have products that is subscription based and once user select lets say product a before he can add to cart he needs to select how many months of subscription he wants after selecting that he can then press the select plan then move to another page to select attributes of the product items that is limited to 2 option or more then after he select and continue he will be on the page of customer info and last step was payment,

So basically it's a 4 page process.

Is this achievable? Can I setup the product types to accommodate subscriptions, with attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

going to post answers to help people that is having the same issue, I used one of this modules to help me fix the issue I am having :

https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_co_pages

hope this can help someone :)